# Change YouTube's css background value in js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

YouTube has these lines in its css:

```
:not(.style-scope)[dark], :not(.style-scope)[dark] {
    --yt-spec-brand-background-solid: #212121;
    --yt-spec-brand-background-primary: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.98);
    --yt-spec-brand-background-secondary: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.95);
    --yt-spec-general-background-a: #181818;
    --yt-spec-general-background-b: #0f0f0f;
    --yt-spec-general-background-c: #030303;
    ...}
```

"html:not" is a new expression to me.
How to change it's background values with js or jquery?

Comment: It's not `html:not` it's `:not(.style-scope)` - so where you might do `table.style` to select `table class=style` this is saying: select html except when it has style-scope class.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking - just add background to this rule or to `$("html")`, or `$("html:not(.style-scope)[dark]").css(...`

Comment: I'm asking for changing YT's background. Your suggestions doesn't seem to change anything. It's only changing if i change it manually through developer tools in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The `:not` pseduo-selector means you want to match with an element that **does not** have the selector in the parentheses. So here `html:not(.style-scope)` means they want these styles to only apply to the html element when it doesn't have the class `style-scope`

Here's the MDN article on the not selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

If you wanted to change the values through javascript, you could change the classes set on the HTML element. Or if you want to change the CSS variables, here's an article on how to do so: https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/

Although based on this code sample, my guess would be they change an attribute for what theme should be applied. Here the attribute they want to match is `dark`. I would assume there's a corresponding `light` attribute and styles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your looking for this?

```
document.querySelector("html:not(.style-scope)");
```

To my knowledge you can use all css selectors using *querySelector* in vanilla js

**To change the background** to black when the html element doesn't have the classname *.style-scope*

```
document.querySelector("html:not(.style-scope)").style.background = "black";
```

Comment: Nope, the background is still grey.

Comment: Maybe if you show more of your code I can help

Comment: It's not my code. It's any other YouTube page. I'm asking for js or jquery code to change page background to black.